# Are there limitations for using the bing news rss feed?

Tags: rss, feed, bing, bing-api

We want to use the bing news rss feed, `https://www.bing.com/news/search?q={query}&format=rss`, but we're not sure if there are any restrictions, i.e. max queries per second or max queries per month. Does anyone know what kind of pricing and restrictions exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the feed's copyright tag:

```
<copyright>Copyright \xc2\xa9 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved. These XML
results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner or for any 
purpose other than rendering Bing results within an RSS aggregator for your 
personal, non-commercial use. Any other use of these results requires express 
written permission from Microsoft Corporation. By accessing this web page or 
using these results in any manner whatsoever, you agree to be bound by the 
foregoing restrictions.</copyright>
```

So personal, non-commercial use is ok, and in that case max queries and quotas are probaby not going to be exeeced.